# Pipenv error when trying to install to virtualenv

Tags: python-3.6, pipenv

I'm trying to setup piping to output a pipfile for my employer. I'm totally new to this, and my system knowledge is lacking. Please can someone help me debug this error?

When I run :

```
pipenv install -e
```

I get the following error :

```
(py3) ➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ pipenv install -e
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: /Users/davidmellor/Pipfile
Using /Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/bin/python (3.6.2) to create virtualenv...
⠋Already using interpreter /Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/bin/python
Using base prefix '/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3'
New python executable in /Users/davidmellor/.local/share/virtualenvs/davidmellor-1NR562gx/bin/python
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libpython3.6m.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/davidmellor/.local/share/virtualenvs/davidmellor-1NR562gx/bin/python
  Reason: image not found
ERROR: The executable /Users/davidmellor/.local/share/virtualenvs/davidmellor-1NR562gx/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/Users/davidmellor' (should be '/Users/davidmellor/.local/share/virtualenvs/davidmellor-1NR562gx')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable

Virtualenv location:
Creating a Pipfile for this project...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/bin/pipenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/Users/davidmellor/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/davidmellor/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Users/davidmellor/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/Users/davidmellor/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/Users/davidmellor/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/davidmellor/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/cli.py", line 435, in install
    selective_upgrade=selective_upgrade,
  File "/Users/davidmellor/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1759, in do_install
    pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
  File "/Users/davidmellor/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 639, in ensure_project
    ensure_pipfile(validate=validate, skip_requirements=skip_requirements, system=system)
  File "/Users/davidmellor/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 288, in ensure_pipfile
    project.create_pipfile(python=python)
  File "/Users/davidmellor/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/project.py", line 607, in create_pipfile
    required_python = self.which('python')
  File "/Users/davidmellor/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 115, in which
    p = os.path.join(location, 'bin', command)
  File "/Users/davidmellor/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/posixpath.py", line 78, in join
    a = os.fspath(a)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

I've tried to modify my PATH within my .bashrc file as follows :

```
PYTHON_BIN_PATH="$/Users/davidmellor/.local/bin"
PATH="$PATH:$PYTHON_BIN_PATH"

export PATH=$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=blog.settings
```

But still having no luck.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'pyenv' package with pipenv.

Install 'pyenv' package by using `brew install pyenv` (if you don't have it).

Install python 3.6.2 using `pyenv install 3.6.2`. In your case you are using anaconda, so you can also install any anaconda version you would like to use. 
Use `pyenv install --list` to see the list of python available versions

Then, export new installed python version to PATH

`export PATH=${PYENV_PYTHON_VERSIONS_HOME}/3.6.2/bin`

Now in 'Piplock' specify the same version.

`[requires]
 python_version = "3.6.2"`

Finally, run remove previous virtualenv and rebuild again.

`pipenv --rm`

`pipenv install --dev`.